# how is strncpy able to copy from source to empty destination?

Tags: c, sockets, memory-management, strncpy

I'm trying to implement basic socket program in C which parses HTTP GET requests for now, in `parse_http_req` function I've declared `char* line;` and after `strncpy` call `line` contains 1st line of HTTP request data. My doubt is I didn't allocate any memory for `line` before I called `strncpy`, how is this code working correctly ? Here is my full `server.c` code (still under development)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>  
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <asm-generic/socket.h>
#include <string.h>

#define DEFAULT_PORT 8080
#define MAX_REQ_QUEUE_SIZE 10
#define MAX_REQ_SIZE 1024
#define DEFAULT_PROTOCOL "http"

enum Methods {
    GET,
    POST,
    PUT,
    OPTIONS,
    DELETE,
    INVALID_METHOD
};

typedef struct Request {
    enum Methods method;
    char *path;
    char *protocol;
    char *body;
    size_t content_length;
} Request;

enum Methods get_req_method(char *req) {

    if (strcmp(req, "GET")) {
        return GET;
    }
    if (strcmp(req, "POST")) {
        return POST;
    }
    if(strcmp(req, "OPTONS")){
        return OPTIONS;
    }
    if (strcmp(req, "PUT")) {
        return PUT;
    }
    if (strcmp(req, "DELETE")) {
        return DELETE;
    }
    return INVALID_METHOD;    
}

void parse_http_req(char *req, size_t req_size) {
    
    int size = 0;
    
    while ((*(req + size) != '\n') && (size < req_size)) {
        size++;
    }

    printf("size: %d\n", size);

    char *line;

    line = strncpy(line, req, size);
    
    line[size] = '\0';

    printf("First line: %s\n", line);
}

void accept_incoming_request(int socket, struct sockaddr_in *address, socklen_t len) {

    int accept_fd;

    socklen_t socklen = len;
    
    while ((accept_fd  = accept(socket, (struct sockaddr *)address, &len)) > 0) {
        char *buffer = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_REQ_SIZE);

        int recvd_bytes = read(accept_fd, buffer, MAX_REQ_SIZE);

        printf("%s\n%ld\n%d\n\n\n", buffer, strlen(buffer), recvd_bytes);

        parse_http_req(buffer, strlen(buffer));

        free(buffer);

        send(accept_fd, "hello", 5, 0);
        
        close(accept_fd);
    }
    shutdown(socket, SHUT_RDWR);
}

int create_socket(struct sockaddr_in *address, socklen_t len) {
    
    int fd, opt = 1;

    if ((fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
        perror("socket creation failed\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if (setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT, &opt,  sizeof(opt))) {  
        perror("setsockopt");  
        return -1;
    } 

    if (bind(fd, (struct sockaddr*)address, len) < 0) {
        perror("Socket bind failed\n");
        return -1;
    }

    return fd;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    short PORT = DEFAULT_PORT;
    
    char *PROTOCOL = DEFAULT_PROTOCOL;

    if (argc > 1) {
        PORT = (short)atoi(argv[1]);
    }

    if (argc > 2) {
        PROTOCOL = argv[2];
    }

    printf("%d %s\n", PORT, PROTOCOL);

    struct sockaddr_in address = {
        sin_family: AF_INET,
        sin_addr: {
            s_addr: INADDR_ANY
        },
        sin_port: htons(PORT)
    };

    int socket;
    
    if ((socket = create_socket(&address, sizeof(address))) < 0) {
        exit(1);
    }

    if (listen(socket, MAX_REQ_QUEUE_SIZE) < 0) {
        perror("Listen failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    accept_incoming_request(socket, &address, sizeof(address));

    return 0;
}
```

If you compile and run server starts at port: `8080` or you can pass desired port as 1st arg like `./server 9000`

To test: `wget http://localhost:8080/dummy/path`

I tried to see if that line `strncpy` piece of code is valid. Here is my `test.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void f1(char *l2, int size) {
    char *l1;
    
    l1 =  strncpy(l1, l2, size);
    
    printf("%s\n", l1);
}

void main() {

    char *l1 = malloc(10);

    char *l2 = "test";

    strncpy(l1, l2, 5);

    printf("%s\n", l1);
     
    free(l1);

    f1(l2, 5);
}
```

As I expected if I allocate some memory for `l1` before calling `strncpy` like in main it's all good. But, getting `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` while executing `function f1`. How is similar piece of code working in my **server.c** but not in this **test.c** program

Comment: The biggest problem with undefined behavior is that sometimes it can appear to work correctly even though the code is incorrect. Use tools like AddressSanitizer to help you find issues like this.

Answer (score 3):

The code `char *line; line = strncpy(line, req, size);` has undefined behavior: `line` is an uninitialized pointer, so you cannot copy anything to it.

My recommendation is [**you should never use `strncpy`**](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/04/03/stop-using-strncpy-already/): it does not do what you think.

In your code, you should instead use `char *line = strndup(req, size);` which allocates memory and copies the string fragment to it. The memory should be freed after use with `free(line)`.

`strndup()` first standardized in POSIX finally becomes part of the C Standard in the latest version, so it is available on most systems, but it your target does not have it, it can be defined this way:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

char *strndup(const char *s, size_t n) {
    char *p;
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < n && s[i] != '\0'; i++)
        continue;
    p = malloc(i + 1);
    if (p != NULL) {
        memcpy(p, s, i);
        p[i] = '\0';
    }
    return p;
}
```

There are other problems in your code:

- `strcmp(req, "GET")` returns `0` is the strings have the same characters, so you should write:

  ```
      if (strcmp(req, "GET") == 0) {
          return GET;
      }
  ```

  or

  ```
      if (!strcmp(req, "GET")) {
          return GET;
      }
  ```
- you should reverse the order of the tests in `while((*(req + size) != '\n') && (size < req_size))` to avoid accessing `req[req_size]`.

- in `accept_incoming_request` you should allocate the destination array with an extra byte for the null terminator and set this null byte at the end of the received packet with:

  ```
    buffer[recvd_bytes] = '\0';
  ```

Comment: `strndup()` is also [standard in C23](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c2x/n3047.pdf), umm, C24.  Which means MSVC will get it in about 2145.

Comment: And I think `memory(p, s, i);` should be `memcpy(p, s, i);`

Comment: `strncat()` can do what the uninitiated tend to think `strncpy()` will do, provided that you first write a string terminator to the first character of the destination.  `strndup()` is a good choice for the OP because they require allocation, too, but if they were copying into an existing object then `strndup()` (and `strdup()`) would not be applicable.

Answer (score 0):

In this code

```
char *line;

line = strncpy(line, req, size);
```

`line` is not explicitly initialized to a specific value; since it's an `auto` (local) variable, its initial value is *indeterminate*, meaning it could be literally anything. The behavior on writing through an invalid pointer is *undefined*, meaning that neither the compiler nor the runtime environment are required to handle the situation in any particular way.

In this particular case that indeterminate initial value just happened to correspond to the address of a writable piece of memory, so your code *appeared* to work without any problems.

However, there's no guarantee you didn't overwrite something important that would have caused a problem later on, or that another thread or process won't write over that memory while you're using it.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why the test program is working as expected(throwing seg fault) but not in server code. Got the point that it's undefined behavior. Is it just coincidence that garbage value in my test program got non-writable place or something like that ? @John

Comment: @Eivor: Entirely coincidence.  Undefined behavior doesn't have to consistent or repeatable from program to program, or from build to build of the same program, or from run to run of the same build.  It isn't even guaranteed to be repeatable if it occurs more than once in the same program.  An expression like `i++ * i++` can give different behavior at different points in the same program.